# The set of values of $x$ for which the expression $\sqrt{3-x}$ is rational.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

For the expression $\sqrt{3-x}$ to be rational $(3-x)$ must be a perfect square.

So some solutions would be: 3, 2, -1, 6, etc.

But fractional solution like $\frac{11}{4}$ would also work.

Is there any way to answer this with one expression in terms of $x$ ?

Comment: $x=3-\frac{p^2}{q^2}$ for integer $p,q$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution set of $y^2=3-x$ can be described by
\begin{align*}
S & =\Bigl\{(x,y)\mid x=\frac{3q^2-p^2}{q^2},\; y=\frac{p}{q}\Bigr\} \\
  & = \Bigl\{\left( \frac{3q^2-p^2}{q^2},\frac{p}{q}\right) \Bigr\}
\end{align*}
where $p,q$ are arbitrary integers with $q\neq 0$.

Comment: The answer is incorrect. $$ x= \dfrac{3q^2-p^2}{q^2} $$

Comment: @LaxmiNarayanBhandari Thank you, corrected.